# How to configure Pycharm to use packages already installed in Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda

I've recently installed Pycharm 2020.1 and set Anaconda as interpreter:

[image]

When I look at the packages installed, only basic packages appear

[image]

Because Anaconda 2020.02 contains many packages (including Jupyter), I expect that Pycharm can recognize them too.

Is it possible to make Pycharm recognize those packages already installed in Anaconda or I must insall them again in Pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new conda environment pick the base conda as an interpreter **Existing Interpreter** -> **Conda environment** -> select base conda:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pavel, I use Anaconda 2020.02 in which the folder structure does not contain `/bin/python` and `/bin/conda`. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/O0bHB52) is the screenshot of my directory. Please elaborate more on `Interpreter` and `Conda executable` path!

Comment: Pick `python` file from your screenshot.